# PWA Add home screen is taking time

Tags: performance, progressive-web-apps

I am trying out to plugin PWA into our mobile website, I have been able to implement all features of PWA without any problem. But I am facing issue while I am trying "Add to Home Screen" feature, it is taking more than 30 secs to create an App Icon on mobile home. This is a bad UX, please advise if we have encountered this issue and what can be done to make it work faster.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the size of your application? it is properly minified? and how's the network performance?

Comment: WebAPKs don't include app source code so it's unlikely to be caused by that. If you consistently get slow installs, I'd recommend [filing a bug with Google](https://crbug.com/new). If it's intermittent it might be temporary service issues with Google.

Comment: yes even I experience this issue